# replacing a text with image using javascript

Tags: javascript

Please Guys, I want to run a script which will replace text with an image, either when it's been typed in an input field or it's outputted from the database: here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    ":-)".replace(/\([0-z]+)\/g,"<img src='smiling_face.gif' />");
</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your code is correct, it replaces a text with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var container = $('body').html();
test = container.replace(/\:\-\)/g,"<img src='smiling_face.gif' />");
$('body').html(test);
```